# I could not connect to database

Tags: asp.net, sql, database

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
       {
    SqlConnection con =    new SqlConnection("Data Source=LENOVO;Initial Catalog=dbMACARON;Integrated Security=True");    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("Select * from PRODUCT");


    public void Bind()
    {
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        con.Open();
        com.Connection = con;
        com.ExecuteNonQuery();
        da.Fill(ds, "PRODUCT");
        GridView1.DataSource = ds;
        GridView1.DataBind();
        con.Close();
    }

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con.Open();
        com.Connection = con;
        SqlDataReader dr;
        dr = com.ExecuteReader();
        string id = "0";


Source Error:


Line 31:     protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
Line 32:     {
Line 33:         con.Open();
Line 34:         com.Connection = con;
Line 35:         SqlDataReader dr;
```

It said error on my con.Open could not open database, what did i go wrong?
sorry im fresh so i need guidance ,

there some source error it tells me

Comment: What is the version of Sql server you are using? Its a sql express edition?

Comment: It would be very helpful to give some more information about the exception. There are a ton of reasons a program can't open a database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using sql express edition try this:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\SQLExpress;Initial Catalog=dbMACARON;Integrated Security=True");
```

Comment: hi there thanks for helping, i using sql server 2008 r2 for my database... and asp.net platfrom... i dont use sql express edition, i dont find this work on sql server 2008 r2. i so confuse now because my friend pc work but mine it have error on the .con

Comment: YES I USE THIS TO CONNECT MY SQL SERVER ASPNETDB.MDF FILES

Answer (score 0):

1. Try using port number with the DB server name
2. What is the authentication mode? Windows Authentication or User id/Password based?
   If it is userId/password based, then you need to provide password also.

Comment: hi thanks for helping me , my lec didt teach me how to use port connect with db... i just simple use the db server name. and th authentication mode is none.. i dont use any password.

Comment: Hi. Can you provide more details about the error message?

Comment: Do you have the necessary permissions to access the Database or the database server?

Comment: after i did this  
new SqlConnection("Data Source=EBG;Initial Catalog=dbMACARON;Integrated Security=True");
now others problem pop out.. 
do you like to teamviewer with me?

Comment: These data sources that you are using, where are they located? Do you have permissions to access them?

Comment: i not sure, in my computer? it on drive C, yes i do have permissions.
try have a look id : 121 645 816 pass : 7wc1z4 (teamviewer) i just need my data snyc with my web

Comment: Data Source=LENOVO\EBG;Initial Catalog=dbMACARON;Integrated Security=True , these are the data sources my computer telling me in asp.net

Comment: Umm..I am not sure why the problem is occurring. You can try these 2 things: 1) Try opening Visual Studio in administrator mode and try 2) Use Integrated Security=SSIP

Comment: Unable to think of anything else at the moment. Will try to consult my colleagues and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

Try this as it is.
1. Go to Tools menu-> folder option-> view tab and unCheck the following checkbox with name that **HIDE EXTENSION FOR KNWON FILE TYPES.**

2.Now crate the file as sql with extension udl i.e sql.udl. It will ask you for confirmation press Yes.

1. Right click on that file and select open with **OLEDB CORE DATASERVICE**. It will open the dialog box as follows.
   ![enter image description here][2]
2. Go to provider tab and select **Microsoft OLEDB PROVIDER FOR SQL SERVER**.. AND THEN CLICK ON NEXT BUTTON.
3. Then copy and paste your server name from SQL SERVER MANAGEMENT STUDIO in the first textbox. on second number select which mode you are using and in the end select the database which you want to use from the dropdown.
4. Click on TEST CONNECTION button it will show you successfull connection .

finally close that window and now open that udl file with notepad. Copy the content starting  from the provider name to the end and paste it into your coding page.

Thats it. It will not show you error again.

Comment: hi there i lost at the picture u trying to show me.. it doesn't show actually..  but these are like new level for me... i dont know how.

Comment: @user3458545 I was trying to post the images for this but due to security reasons of stackoverflow i can't. But if you follow it as it is then you can do it.

Answer (score 0):

I HAVE FIX IT MY SELF!! BUT THANKS FOR EVERYONE FOR TRYING HELPING ME OUT !! THANKS YOU!!

what i do is i put double "\" between lenovo and ebg example in sqp connection..

EXAMPLE:

public partial class SignUp : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    **SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=LENOVO\EBG; Initial** Catalog=dbMACARON; integrated security= True");
    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("Select * from CUSTOMER");
    public void Bind()
    {
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        con.Open();
        com.Connection = con;
        com.ExecuteNonQuery();
        da.Fill(ds, "CUSTOMER");
        GridView1.DataSource = ds;
        GridView1.DataBind();
        con.Close();
     }

weird in this web it didt show double "\" in here... but nway thanks.